# Rooting Unknown Device

Tags: rooting, adb, root-access, busybox

Actually i want to root not-branded tablet. That table is running Android Jelly bean 4.2.2, Kernel 3.0.8+.

Current my status:

- From the start i have root access in adb shell
- I managed update su binary from legacy to 3.1.1 (su binary located at /system/xbin/)
- I also installed Superuser app as System app
- And busybox already existed and i think there is no need for updating

You may think the device is rooted, but it's not. Even Superuser app can't access root permissions.

I don't want to use one click solutions and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure applications can access the root, you may need to enable it from the Developer Options menu in your device's settings. Once in the Developer Options menu, look for the root access option and select from 'Apps only', 'ADB only' and 'Apps and ADB'. You might have to accept a warning about security, too.

If developer settings isn't visible, try the usual method of hitting 'Build Number' several times in the Phone/Tablet Info section in the settings.

Source: I had a problem similar to this after rooting my S3 and installing CyanogenMod 12.

Comment: In CM 11 and CM 12, I found that the settings  Apps/ADB root  cannot be enabled without first enabling Developer Options, so I wonder how OP gets root shell on ADB if not managed by this setting. I guess  some `su` binary with no interception apk.  And if you end up disabling Developer options somehow, the root settings would disable as well. Besides, CM 11 and CM 12 are based on Android 4.4.x and 5.x.x. This setting that you mentioned might not be found in 4.2.2. Not at least in 4.2.1 of my device. But anyway, if your answer somehow works out for OP,  then its good. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Firelord. I understand where you are coming from, but I couldn't think of anything else at this time.